# Printing special characters in a for loop instead of numbers

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is what the program is printing:

```
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)
(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)
(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)
```

What I want it to do is to print ( * ) in replace of (1,1). I know an if statement is involved, but I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the condition I should put.

```
public class loops {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i=1;
    for (int k = i-1; i< 4; i++)
    {
        int j =1;
        for (int l = j-1; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (k ==i+1 && l == j+1) System.out.print("( * )");

            else System.out.print("("+k+","+l+")");
            l++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        k++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your loop setup is quite bizarre ( `for (int k = i-1; i< 4; i++)` ) - why don't you just use 1 variable to pilot the loop?  Like `for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)`.  What you're doing is extremely confusing and I can't see any benefit to it...

Comment: I was trying to do something to where the (1,1) would check the surrounding numbers without including itself. Does that make sense? I'm not the best with words.

Comment: Try to explain it a bit better.!

Comment: You want to do that only for (1,1) or every time you find the same occurrences.? For example (2,2), (3,3) and so on.?

Comment: You want to check the (1,0) and (1,2) in order to determine that you are in (1,1).? This is what you mean.?

Comment: lets say that instead of (num,num), there were * and -, and I would want to check how many * there are surrounding the * or - that is at (1,1) without including (1,1). I hope that was better.

Comment: and yes, just for (1,1).

Comment: OUhhhhhhh...Now i think you complicated even more.. Please try to update you question with an example of what you want to achieve and what you want to be the expected output. Take some time and structure your thought so we can understand better what you request.! Please be as clear as possible and try to include every important detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if condition is part of it, but you are also complicating your for loops, try this:

```
public class loops {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     for (int k = 0; k<3; k++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j<3; j++)
       {
         if (k ==1 && j == 1)
         {
           System.out.print("( * )");
         } else {
           System.out.print("("+k+","+j+")");
         }
       }
       System.out.println("");
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is that the only way? I was trying to do something to where the (1,1) would check the surrounding numbers without including itself. Does that make sense? I'm not the best with words.

Comment: Are you looking for an `if` statement that matches the center of the square without testing the literal values of `k == 1 && j == 1`?

Answer (score -1):

you should just validate if both values are equal to 1 then print (*) , otherwise the result